# icreated a table in migration and given a column_name as :name, but it not created in schema, so how to add the column name in that existing table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created a table in migration and given a column_name as :name, but its not created in schema, so how to add the column name in that existing table?

```
manish@manish:~/workspace/depot$ rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
Multiple migrations have the name CreateUsers
/home/manish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:608:in `block in migrations'
/home/manish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:600:in `map'
/home/manish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:600:in `migrations'
/home/manish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:701:in `migrations'
/home/manish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:656:in `migrate'
/home/manish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:549:in `up'
/home/manish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:530:in `migrate'
/home/manish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:161:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/manish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/home/manish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rename the column through another migration. just create another migration and add

```
def self.up
  rename_column :table_name, :old_column, :new_column
end
```

and run the migration.

Comment: great. what was the problem ?